# Is it frowned upon to use another preposition besides 'on' when using 'dwell on'? Would 'dwell over' work?

Tags: expressions, prepositions, word-usage, cliche

Someone I know is trying to settle on a particular lyric for a song. The lyric is currently:

> No more seeking answers to old mysteries
>
> No more digging deep into the past
>
> No use dwelling **over** ancient victories
>
> Except by me they were forgotten fast

Just wondering if Stack Exchange would think that the use of 'over' here instead of 'on' works...

Comment: With the *mull* or *contemplate* sense, as in your example, your options (going by the benchmark "licensed by broad usage") are essentially *on* or *upon*. There are several other prepositions which regularly collocate with *dwell*, but they're used almost exclusively with the "reside" sense. In decreasing order of use, the ten prepositions which [collocate most frequently in *dwell <prep>*](https://imgur.com/a/R6Ns7) are *on, in, upon, with, among, within, for*, and *beneath*. The word *over* doesn't make an appearance, and if it did, it would be in the locative, not metaphorical, sense.

Comment: Well, you can always "dwell in an apartment" or "dwell in the past".  "Dwelling over" isn't real common, but is certainly used, and should be perfectly fine in a lyric.

Comment: Easy find with Ngram: [They were too busy to dwell over what might have been](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ukuf90ugC8kC&pg=PT87&dq=%22dwell+over%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJvdTen43TAhVqs1QKHd0lBo8Q6AEILTAE#v=onepage&q=%22dwell%20over%22&f=false).

Comment: @HotLicks *Dwelling over* isn't used in the contemplate sense, see above. But as you say (and I said), *dwell over* could be used in the *reside* sense, as a locative *he dwelled over a house of ill repute*, or even *he dwelled over his beer*, to combined both *contemplate* and the locative. But not, not *he dwelled over her death*. That won't work. In re: lyrics, sure, a poetic license frees you from all chains. But then some can't distinguish between free men and madmen.

Comment: [but we will not dwell over it at great length](https://books.google.com/books?id=W3dbAAAAMAAJ&q=%22dwell+over%22&dq=%22dwell+over%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4i4OToI3TAhUJw1QKHQRUASM4ChDoAQgqMAM) -- [T0 dwell over the noble old patriarch of a building at any length, however, would be almost an absurdity in these pages; for its features are as familiar to every native American as is the alphabet itself.](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y7o9AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA300&dq=%22dwell+over%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMsIfsoI3TAhWkr1QKHc4QA-0Q6AEIOjAG#v=onepage&q=%22dwell%20over%22&f=false)

Comment: @DanBron - See my examples.

Comment: @HotLicks Fair enough, but I worry we can find a handful of examples of anything, but if a construction hasn't been used enough to be familiar to most speakers, it will succeed only in drawing attention to itself, and make people think about phrasing, nor meaning. It certainly did that to me, reading OP's example.

Comment: @DanBron - But when you read those examples (without prejudice) there is nothing in them that "sounds wrong", and you would not tend to even notice the rareness of the usage.

Comment: @HotLicks Your first example, "what might have been" hit my ear wrong, similar to OP's example. The second, the Victorian one, sounded fine. Not sure what accounts for the difference. Maybe the Victorian context allowed me to accept more self-conscious and purple language? I don't know. Maybe it's me.

Comment: So what about the third example?

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't have noticed that there was anything unusual going on in that lyric.  It's just fine.

Answer (score 2):

"Dwell over" isn't a standard English expression, but people would understand what you mean. Maybe you could change "dwelling" to something else:

- Mulling over
- Raking over
- Crowing over
- Going over

None of these have *exactly* the same meaning as (what I think you mean by) dwelling over, but may deliver the same overall message that you're aiming for.

Comment: Thank you for providing a list of alternatives. I found it quite educational. However, I cant help but point out that "to crow over" means "to gloat, boast, or exult" and is not a valid analogue to the other three expressions.

Comment: You could add *brooding over* to your list. @PashaSyrnikov I think in the context of the original lyric, *crowing over* could make sense (since the things being dwelt upon are "ancient victories"). But of course, one of the advantages of the original verb is its ambiguity, which would be weakened or lost with most of these options.